# javafx keytyped event not working

Tags: java, events, combobox, javafx, keyevent

I have a JAVAFX editable combobox on which key typed and key pressed events are not firing while key released event is firing. However, If I change the combobox to textfield, it works.
FXML:

```
 <ComboBox fx:id="combo_box" editable="true" layoutX="311.0" layoutY="194.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="300.0" promptText="Enter your name" onKeyTyped="#keyAction"  />
```

FXMLController:

```
public void keyAction(KeyEvent event)
{
System.out.println("Works");
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something which works. You can use the "getEditor" method of the combobox, to get the KEY_TYPED event works. Put this code in your controller :

```
this.combo_box.getEditor().setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent e) -> {
     System.out.println("Works");
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You, Sir, are the MVP. It works. Thanks.

So, instead of binding the event to the combobox, I have to bind it to the editor of the combobox.